# In Blackberry package javax.microedition.amms.* prob

Tags: blackberry, import

I am developing a QR code scanning application using Zxing library in Blackberry JDE 4.6. For that I have used different package in packages of `javax.microedition.amms.*` . Suddenly that imports are working fine, suddenly it failed to import any package javax.microedition.amms.* and starting to throwing problem. What is probable cause of this prob? I have already tried to repair the the JDE by the installer. But it does not help anything. What is way out from it?

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry JDE 4.6 does not JSR-234 features. So it is not supporting javax.microedition.amms.*